# Why isnt my function called in a list? (Angular Dropdown)

Tags: angular, function, components, dropdown

```
<div class="dropdown" dropdown [dropdownToggle]="false" (onOpen)="ewa()" (onClose)="doSomeActionOnClose()">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" dropdown-open>My Heroes</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li value="Denhaag" onclick="goToDenHaag()"><a>Den haag</a></li>
    <li  value="Amsterdam" onclick="goToAmsterdam()"><a>Amsterdam</a></li>
    <li value="Utrecht" onclick="goToUtrecht()"><a>Utrecht</a></li>
    <li value="Gouda" onclick="goToGouda()"><a>Gouda</a></li>
    <li value="Eindhoven" onclick="goToEindhoven()"><a>Eindhoven</a></li>
    <li value="Rotterdam" onclick="goToRotterdam()"><a>Rotterdam</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Why is my console saying *function* is not defined when I select that option? The functions stated in the onclick params do exist in my component as follows:

```
public goToRotterdam = () => {

let position = {lat:  51.9244201, lng:  4.4777325};
this.gmapWrapper.panTo(position);
}
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: goToRotterdam is not defined

Any help is appreciated

Edit:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';
import {GMapsService} from "./map.service";
import * as data from './inkomen.json';
import * as inbraakdata from '../../assets/output.json';
import * as data_latlon from './inkomen_latlon.json';
import * as inbraak_latlon from './output.json';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {last} from "@angular/router/src/utils/collection";
import {DropdownModule} from "ngx-dropdown";
import { AgmCoreModule, GoogleMapsAPIWrapper, AgmInfoWindow, AgmDataLayer, CircleManager, AgmCircle } from '@agm/core';
import {$} from "protractor";

@Component({
  selector : 'googlemap',
  templateUrl: 'maps.html',
  styleUrls: ['map.component.css']
})
export class GoogleMapsComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild(GoogleMapsAPIWrapper) private gmapWrapper: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper;
  arr = [];
  arr2 = [];

  jsonLatlon;
map : any;
jsonData;
  result;
  inkomen
  count = 0;
  results: any;
  pages =['abc','bca','pqr'];

  constructor(private http: Http, private mapservice: GMapsService, map: MapsAPILoader) {
  this.jsonData = data;
    this.jsonLatlon = data_latlon
    this.results = inbraak_latlon;
    this.result = inbraak_latlon;


  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.jsonData)
    console.log(this.jsonLatlon.data)
    console.log(this.results)
    this.convert()
    let pos1 = {lat: 52.0704978, lng: 4.3006999};
    this.gmapWrapper.setCenter(pos1)
    this.gmapWrapper.setZoom(12);

    }





  title: string = 'My first AGM project';
  //lat: number = 52.1941679;
 // lng: number = 4.6820146;

  public ewa = () => {

    var li = document.getElementById("Denhaag")
    console.log("ewa" +li.innerText);



    alert("ewa");
    let position = {lat: 52.0704978, lng: 4.3006999};
    this.gmapWrapper.panTo(position);
    this.gmapWrapper.setZoom(12);

  };

  public goToDenHaag = () => {
    let position = {lat: 52.0704978, lng: 4.3006999};
    this.gmapWrapper.panTo(position);
  };

  public goToAmsterdam = () => {


    let position = {lat: 52.379189, lng: 4.899431};
    this.gmapWrapper.panTo(position);
  };

  public goToUtrecht = () => {


    let position = {lat: 52.0928768, lng: 5.104480};
    this.gmapWrapper.panTo(position);
  };

  public goToGouda = () => {


    let position = {lat: 52.0115205, lng: 4.7104633};
    this.gmapWrapper.panTo(position);
  };

  public goToEindhoven = () => {


    let position = {lat: 51.441642, lng: 5.4697225};
    this.gmapWrapper.panTo(position);
  };

 goToRotterdam() {
 console.log("We gaan naar Roffa");
    let position = {lat:  51.9244201, lng:  4.4777325};
    this.gmapWrapper.panTo(position);
  };

  public goToAlmere = () => {


    let position = {lat: 52.3507849, lng: 5.2647016};
    this.gmapWrapper.panTo(position);
  };

  public goToGroningen = () => {


    let position = {lat: 53.2193835, lng: 6.5665018};
    this.gmapWrapper.panTo(position);
  };

  public goToNijmegen = () => {



    let position = {lat: 51.8125626, lng: 5.8372264};
    this.gmapWrapper.panTo(position);
  };

}
```

Added the component class for the map.
Some text. Some more text*

Comment: Did you try with the Angular event syntax: `(click)="goToRotterdam()"`? `onclick` is a DOM element property, it doesn't know where to find your method.

Comment: I tried it that way, but the method is still not firing somehow..

Comment: You can compare your code with [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cdcx0S0sSqPvFYn7Y1sk?p=preview). The click event works for Rotterdam (you can see it in the console).

Comment: @ConnorsFan where do I see the console? And why are the list items below the button?

Comment: The console is seen with the F12 key (on Windows at least). One important difference in my plunker: it does not implement the dropdown; it only shows the list. In your case, if the dropdown closes when you select an item, you can try to handle `(mousedown)` instead of `(click)`.

Comment: I see that it works there indeed. But dont know why it is not working here locally.. I get a strange error though which I do not understand. Please check my comment below the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your methods like this in your component,

```
goToRotterdam() {
  const position = {lat:  51.9244201, lng:  4.4777325};
  this.gmapWrapper.panTo(position);
}
```

And also use the `(click)` event as ConnorsFan mentioned.

Comment: I get this strange error message: stats.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: _.vf is not a function
    at new D1 (stats.js:4)

Comment: please post your component code, it's hard to debug otherwise

Comment: That error is likely due to the way you include the google maps api.

Comment: @user3660293 - You can try to just send a string to the console in `goToRotterdam`, to see if everything is OK with the `click` handling.

Comment: No even the string doesnt get logged to the console. @ConnorsFan